# getting error : TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function

Tags: reactjs, dotenv

getting error : `TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function` when  i tried to use get value from .env file, can anyone please help me why i am getting this error?  here i have uploaded my code, can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ? any help will be really appreciated.

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs');
const envConfig = dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync('.env'))
for (const k in envConfig) {
  process.env[k] = envConfig[k]
}
```

Comment: it appears that your require('fs') is not able to locate the fs module in your project.

Comment: fs module is part of node's core modules and so you don't need to install it again, and if you see that `TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function` this means that the readFileSync is not defined in that module or the installation for your nodejs is not complete. See if you can reinstall your nodejs

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I want to remind that `fs` will not work in the browser. This is by design as to protect your filesystem from potential security threats.

Did you use `create-react-app` when you were creating **ReactJs** project?

If it is the case, the following solution will fix this issue.

> In your .env file, you have to append **REACT_APP_** to all env variables to make it work.
>
> Don't forget to restart your server after changing it.

For example :

This works -

```
REACT_APP_MYVAR=yourSecret
```

This doesn't

```
MYVAR=yourSecret
```

You can read the reference link in here.
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/